# FA Icon Glow / Shadow

Tags: html, css, icons, font-awesome

Is there some way I can create an icon "glow" effect on a font-awesome icon?

I have tried the following:

```
<i class="icon-thumbs-down glow"/>
```

and

```
.glow { box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #fff; }
```

Unfortunately this results in a "square" white glow around the bounding box of the icon. How can I make a glow that contours to the shape of the icon?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Figured it out 30 seconds later:

Font awesome is just a font, so you can do a text shadow:

```
.glow { text-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #FFFFFF; }
```

Comment: You are awesome! Greetings from 17'

Comment: anyone know how to do this with the new native components... fortawesome?